# Can I wire an outlet off of this switch?

Tags: wiring, switch, neutral, multiway-switch

I have a three way switch that I would like to wire a regular wall outlet off of. The wall outlet would be wired off of the switch in picture #2. The black wire in picture 2 has constant 120V to it. What I can't figure out for sure is if there is a neutral in the switch that I could also tie into? I am wondering if the black and white capped together are actually acting as neutral in this case or if there isn't one at all! The black and white tied together have a piece of tape labeled "not to light" leading me to believe this likely doesn't have a neutral. Any advice would be much appreciated. I've included the other switch to help figure out how this thing is actually wired.

[image: A]

[image: B]

---

Thank you everyone for the answers! As far as we know there are only two switched to this set of lights. The house has had some crazy stuff in it before so it wouldn’t surprise me if this was an odd setup. I certainly won’t proceed with any further plans of adding the outlet!

Comment: The first switch appears to be a 4-way, not a 3-way - are there 3 or more switches that control this light?

Comment: This is definitely a 3/4/3 way switch network.  Given that I see white in use as a traveler, **neutral is definitely not in any of these boxes**.  Even if you found neutral, always-hot would not be there.  I bet power comes into the lamp. If you have a 3rd switch location which does nothing, it's possible someone mis-wired this 3-4-3 way circuit. Happens all the time.

Answer (score 4):

That's some strange wiring. No indication that you have a neutral - or if you do, there's a code violation going on involving it.

The /2 cable to the left in the lower picture has black going to the black connection on the 3-way switch. The white is joined (<s>"not to light"</s> "hot to light" connection) to a black wire in the /3 cable along with the two travelers (red white) of the 3-way switch.

<s>If the /2 cable is incoming power, you have a neutral, and you have a code violation (neutral on black) in the /3 cable. Easy enough to check if you turn off the breaker, disconnect those wires keeping track of what was what, and check voltage between the black and white there in isolation.</s>

<s>If, in fact, that is the case, and for some reason black is being used to carry a neutral elsewhere, the code fix might be as simple as tracking down ALL the ends of ALL thoose cables and swapping white and black (use red/black for travelers, white neutral; so the current "black-white" join would become white-white.) If that's not the case, not sure what's going on, exactly, just yet. *i.e.* **please don't proceed on that path** without verifying exactly what is going on with the /2 cable first, and then tracking down all the ends of the /3 cables.</s>

It could be that the /2 cable is a switch loop from/to the light, with unswitched power incorrectly on black, the white wire incorrectly not black or red (or other hot color, but it's usually one of those) marked, and the "not to light" label is a lie. **Or you mis-read "hot" as "not" which could be easy depending on penmanship, meaning it says "hot to light" and yup, it's a slightly wrong old-style switch loop.** In that case I expect to see the black wire ultimately connecting to the black terminal on the far-end 3-way switch I expect to find.

Comment: Key insight obtained.